How to define a Typescript type that is an object containing records, which are all the same type with varying keys
I'm trying to define types for the data-object for a given Steam whitelist (the steamWhitelistObject type).
The whitelist is an object containing key-value pairs. The key is a string and the data is another record.
// Types for data fetched from Steam.
type steamRecKey = string; // Steam game ID which is a number in string form.
// Fields are predefined by Steam.
type steamRecValue = {
    name: string; // Game title.
    priority: number; // User/default priority list ordering.
};
type steamRec = Record<steamRecKey, steamRecValue>;
// JS object converted from whitelist data fetched from Steam.
type steamWhitelistObject = {
    // multiple or 0 Records with steamRec type in here
}; // Each entry represents a game

If the whitelist was an array I would define the whitelist type as
type steamWhitelistArr = Array<steamRec>;

What is the equivalent with curly-braces?
Here is some sample data. The outermost curly-braces form the whitelist. There are 2 games in this whitelist.
{
    '1599600': {
    name: 'PlateUp!',
    capsule: 'https://shared.akamai.steamstatic.com/store_item_assets/steam/apps/1599600/header_292x136.jpg?t=1716562055',
    review_score: 9,
    review_desc: 'Overwhelmingly Positive',
    reviews_total: '12,871',
    reviews_percent: 96,
    release_date: '1659621694',
    release_string: '4 Aug, 2022',
    platform_icons: '<span class="platform_img win"></span>',
    subs: [ [Object] ],
    type: 'Game',
    screenshots: [
      'ss_8c944c593113598b6446b6b5d07962a10fe79ec6.jpg',
      'ss_2fb45e66d1b4e8c3d8fe6743fad278bcc082c2d5.jpg',
      'ss_833de2e09f19972bb9e7db021c793da6afdab8a0.jpg',
      'ss_5cdb7d8147767fece03a9a69a10af64a2e0c5e47.jpg'
    ],
    review_css: 'positive',
    priority: 0,
    added: 1703269627,
    background: 'https://shared.akamai.steamstatic.com/store_item_assets/steam/apps/526870/page_bg_generated_v6b.jpg?t=1711646062',
    rank: 700,
    tags: [ 'Co-op', 'Management', 'Cooking', 'Roguelite', 'Building' ],
    is_free_game: false,
    deck_compat: '3',
    win: 1
  },
  '1778820': {
    name: 'TEKKEN 8',
    capsule: 'https://shared.akamai.steamstatic.com/store_item_assets/steam/apps/1778820/header_292x136.jpg?t=1716796901',
    review_score: 6,
    review_desc: 'Mostly Positive',
    reviews_total: '20,480',
    reviews_percent: 70,
    release_date: '1706223600',
    release_string: '25 Jan, 2024',
    platform_icons: '<span class="platform_img win"></span>',
    subs: [ [Object] ],
    type: 'Game',
    screenshots: [
      'ss_62e6ec252bc1a641e8e42dba07f23631d5da85e6.jpg',
      'ss_99dabe34abc0f92adc39d7099908c9540be7eb3f.jpg',
      'ss_bbd38a5fe748ec966cbc85ffcd4931f0f2da8ffd.jpg',
      'ss_7c55021d3ba8e4f14c6d9dbea9f19d9b7665d5f0.jpg'
    ],
    review_css: 'positive',
    priority: 0,
    added: 1706285265,
    background: 'https://shared.akamai.steamstatic.com/store_item_assets/steam/apps/526870/page_bg_generated_v6b.jpg?t=1711646062',
    rank: 639,
    tags: [ 'Fighting', 'Action', '3D Fighter', 'Multiplayer', 'eSports' ],
    is_free_game: false,
    deck_compat: '2',
    win: 1
  },
}

Each steamRecKey has a unique value so I cannot define a field name. I believe this would also not allow multiple records in the same object?
I am also not happy to just define it as 'object' which would defeat the purpose.

If I'm not mistaken, you already have a type that partially describes the sample data: type steamRec = Record<steamRecKey, steamRecValue>;.

@RobertRendell The intent is for records with the steamRec type to be the 'elements' of the whitelist. I want define the whitelist as to only contain steamRecs.
Have I gotten this wrong?

Seems like the naming of the types is maybe confusing and seems like you've already solved this. You can do the following steps: 1) remove steamWhitelistObject, 2) rename steamRec to SteamWhitelist, 3) rename steamRecValue to SteamGame.

Are you looking for type SteamWhitelistObject = Record<string, SteamRec>? If so, I can write up an answer or, more likely, find a q/a this duplicates. If not, please [edit] to make it clear what's missing. Also note that it is unconventional to use lowerCamelCase for custom type names and therefore distracts from the content of your question; please [edit] to use UpperCamelCase instead.

@RobertRendell It seems you are correct. Thanks for the quick answer.
I'll go ahead and edit the question.
